# How To Check Name Already Availability

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Here i am trying to check employee name availability while creating the new employee. While Creating the user if the employee name inserted is already available is table it should show already exists and if not it shouls show available message.
Here is my Employee model class

```
  [Table("tblEmployee")]
public class Employee
{

    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Name Cannot Be Empty")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name Cannot Be Empty")]
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name Cannot Be Empty")]
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

Below Is Create Method In EmployeeController

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Employee employee)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (employee.Name!=employee.Name)
            {
                db.Employees.Add(employee);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.errorMessage = "Name Already Available";
                return (ViewBag.errorMessage);
            }           

        }
        else
        {
            return View("Create");
        }
    }
```

Below Is Create.cshtml

```
@model Practise.Models.Employee

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
 }
 <h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
 {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Employee</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>

        @ViewBag.errorMessage
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Gender, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Gender, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Gender, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.City, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.City, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.City, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

}

Comment: `employee.Name!=employee.Name` why doesn't my name equal to my name?

Comment: On the `POST` action you should add a line code to get all the Employees finding them by `employee.Name`. If the result is `null`, then you can add him to the table. Also, as @TânNguyễn said, `employee.Name!=employee.Name` is probably the most useless thing to do, pay attention

Comment: Most employers, sooner or later, will realise that many people in the real world can have the same names. Using employee name as a unique key tends not to work (the employees tend to complain if you force them to change their names). Also, you need to consider what happens if two people submit at exactly the same time. They both submit. Both checks pass. Both new records are created. Oh dear! At the *least*, you should enforce uniqueness down at the database level and you have to write code to cope with uniqueness being violated.

Comment: That if condition if(employee.Name != employee.Name) doesn't make sense. Instead you can try if(!db.Employees.Any(t=>t.Name == employee.name))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your create method should look like

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    // Check if employee with the same name already exists
    var existingEmployee = db.Employees.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name == employee.Name);

    // No
    if (existingEmployee == null)
    {
        db.Employees.Add(employee);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
     }
     // Yes
     else
     {
         ViewBag.errorMessage = "Name not available";
         return (ViewBag.errorMessage);
      }           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line of code doesn't make sense:

```
employee.Name!=employee.Name
```

You are attempting to compare the exact same employees name with itself.

Instead, you should search db.Employees by name, with something like:

```
var doesEployeeExist = db.Employees.Any(e => e.Name == employee.Name);
```

if "doesEployeeExist" is false, you know the name isn't in use, and you are free to create a new one.

However, you should be aware that it is possible for people to have the same names (first & last), especially as the company grows in size.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Any()` in `Linq`. Like this:

```
// This will check if there is an existing name in your database
bool IsEmployeeExist = db.Employees.Any(e => e.Name.Equals(employee.Name));

if(IsEmployeeExist){
  // Show Error Message
} else {
  // Do insert...
}
```

Though I think that validating Employee Name is too general as there will be a lot of people who could have the same name.